# How do I use our private key to make a web service call?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, wsdl, client

We're using Java 6, JBoss 7.1.1 and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  I'm trying to write an application that will request data from a WSDL on a corporate web site and then write that data back to a local database.  Our corporate group has asked for the public key of a signed-by-authority client certificate (self-signed is fine for QA) of the machine that will be requesting the data, saying that they will use that to send SSL responses back to us and we should use our private key to send requests up to them.

I'm clueless about how to do this.  Normally I would use JAX-WS to create client WSDL code and communicating with the web service, adding the server's public certificate to our trust store.  But in this case, I have no idea how to tell the web service client to use the requesting machine's private key to encrypt data for the purposes of making a WSDL request.

Grateful for any example code or other reference material to pull this off. -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no idea how to tell the web service client to use the requesting machine's private key to encrypt data for the purposes of making a WSDL request.

That doesn't make sense. There is no such thing as encrypting with a private key. Anybody could decrypt it, the public key being, err, public. Let us hope that's not what they are asking for. It's far from clear but they are most probably asking for one of two things:

1. Use a client certificate when speaking SSL to them. All you have to do for this is use the keystore containing the private key and its certificate: JSSE will do the rest. OR
2. Digitally sign the request using your private key. There are APIs for this.

Get them to clarify which it is.